npm install errors "gyp ERR!" "info run sqlite3@3.1.13 install { code: 1, signal: null }"
Trying to install matrix-recorder:
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/argit/matrix-recorder.git
$ cd matrix-recorder/
$ npm install

it does not install and I receive these errors
449 info run sqlite3@3.1.13 install { code: 1, signal: null }
...
457 error gyp ERR! cwd /opt/git_clone/matrix-recorder/node_modules/sqlite3
457 error gyp ERR! node -v v22.3.0
457 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
457 error gyp ERR! Node-gyp failed to build your package.
457 error gyp ERR! Try to update npm and/or node-gyp and if it does not help file an issue with the package author.
...

I would like help understanding what these mean and why they might occur so I can install this program.
I tried updating node-gyp like it suggested, following instructions from the node-gyp docs on github:
$ npm explore npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script -g -- npm_config_global=false npm install node-gyp@latest
I receive the following error:
npm error code EACCES
npm error syscall mkdir
npm error path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules
npm error errno -13
npm error Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules'
npm error     at async mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:863:10)
npm error     at async /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:624:20
npm error     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm error     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:325:11)
npm error     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:142:5)
npm error     at async Install.exec (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:150:5)
npm error     at async Npm.exec (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:207:9)
npm error     at async module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli/entry.js:74:5) {
npm error   errno: -13,
npm error   code: 'EACCES',
npm error   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm error   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules'
npm error }
npm error
npm error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm error It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm error
npm error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm error the command again as root/Administrator.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/data0angel/.npm/_logs/2024-06-28T12_52_49_876Z-debug-0.log
npm error code 243
npm error path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c npm_config_global=false npm install node-gyp@latest
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/data0angel/.npm/_logs/2024-06-28T12_52_49_747Z-debug-0.log


If the command fails with a permissions error, please try sudo and then the command.

So from my home directory I try the same command with sudo:
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

added 791 packages, and audited 955 packages in 26s

176 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Not sure what this means. Tried running $ npm audit and $ sudo npm audit and it returned 0 vulnerabilities. But no errors there so I go back to the matrix-recorder directory and run $ npm install again, but I receive the same errors.

Please include the key parts of the error logs and messages here. Asking us to follow links offsite to get to logs or further details is discouraged here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I tried installing following your steps. I believe these are the error messages that matter during compilation of sqlite3:
npm error In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:148,
npm error                  from ../src/database.h:10,
npm error                  from ../src/statement.cc:7:
npm error ../../nan/nan_callbacks.h:55:23: error: ‘AccessorSignature’ is not a member of ‘v8’

AccessorSignature has been removed from V8. The package still depends on sqlite3 ^3.1.8. The last 3.x series of sqlite3 was released 7 years ago.
Unfortunately, likely the package is too old to be usable on a modern Node.js, e.g., v22.
